# Failed to invoke the service.

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I am getting this error:
Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
Instance failure.

here is my code :

```
 void ConnectToDb()
    {
        connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        connStringBuilder.DataSource = @"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB";
        connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "WRESTLING.MDF";
        connStringBuilder.Encrypt = true;
        connStringBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
        connStringBuilder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
        connStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        connStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        string temp = @"Server=EC2AMAZ-FN5N011\\MSSQLSERVER;Database=C:\APP_DATA\WRESTLING.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        string temp1 = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C:\APP_DATA\WRESTLING.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        conn = new SqlConnection(temp);
        comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        }
```

Comment: The message `Failed to invoke the service` usually refers to a WCF service (look at "Related" to the right, on this page). You are showing a DB connection string. Are you sure you aren't mixing something up or maybe there is more code to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to connect to a local database file (.mdf) you can use the following connection string syntax with `AttachDbFilename`:

```
@"Data Source=(local);AttachDbFilename=C:\APP_DATA\WRESTLING.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"
```

Comment: I used your code and now I am getting this: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\APP_DATA\WRESTLING.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Could you try with this options also? `User Instance=True;`